# Why would Stack Overflow code blocks (only) suddenly be displayed in italics?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, formatting

Okay, it's not April 1st, so the new fonts must be serious. I'd like to express a like or dislike of the new fonts to those who decide such things without starting a flame war. Or is there an option to customize them from the browser?

**Edit**
Apologies, the former title/question about font feedback is no longer correct. This seems to be a Windows system change specific to my pc, but also seems to only affect SO/SE code blocks only (on Chrome and Edge) and nothing else!

**Edit**
Okay, I did search first, I promise, but did not see the posts on Meta Stack Exchange about the May 2021 font change, but that's not what this is. Does however seem from your comments that this is something I'm seeing, not anyone else. The 'pre' or 'code' fonts (even as I type this) are all **italic**, almost a Comic Sans Mono *(edit...it's really Cascadia Mono)*. Nothing about the new fonts that people have taken images of. So my browser is set (as always has been) to show 'fixed width' as Consolas. And frankly Git and MSDN all show code correctly, leading me to believe this is something specific to the SO site. Any ideas?

Comment: See [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/289905).

Comment: SE doesn't provide any special way to customize the fonts used. However, you can always use the inherent capabilities of your operating system or browser to customize which fonts are used (and there might be something there which is set up within either of those in an unusual manner which results in you seeing fonts most of us aren't). You can also, of course, use userstyles or userscripts to make changes to the webpage user interface, including changing the fonts used.

Comment: This is likely related to [Code blocks and markup font looks bolder because of Cascadia Mono - is this intentional?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368632/348196). See also: [How can I change the fonts of the code snippets in Stack Overflow back to Consolas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375847/348196)

Comment: Usually it involves "don't forget that MSE exists, look there too" :) It looks like it is happening more that things are only announced on MSE. So the post to provide feedback under will be found there.

Comment: @Gimby I thought this was MSE. Sigh. This is SOM...

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the link, but for sure something changed this week (Feb 14, 2022). And I use SO every day, I would have noticed. All 'pre' or 'code' is in italics. Not happening to others? Really? My Chrome 'pre' font is set to 'Consolas'. Yes I have Windows Terminal but have had for a couple of months.

Comment: @mdisibio did your Chrome [auto update](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2022/) on that date?

Comment: @RobertLongson Even if it did, what should I look for this one-off behavior? The custom fonts still is set to Consolas for fixed width. And Edge is also displaying the crazy italics. BUT...only on my work pc, not home pc, so yes, likely something policy related, but I can't figure out where to look. And seems to only have affected SO/SE sites.

Comment: Presumably you'd use [this tool](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/)

Comment: Please, [stop using "Edit" everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Rules and guidelines intended for the main site don't necessarily apply to meta. The edits definitely have a useful function for this particular post.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the links from @41686d6564 which point to discussions from a year ago about the editor for Team's chat, the workaround, as ridiculous as it seems, is to uninstall `Cascadia Mono` (not `Cascadia Code`) from Windows. (`Cascadia Mono` is the italic font that I wrote looked like `Comic Sans Mono`)

- I have no idea why all of a sudden this particular week in 2022 it
  suddenly affected the display of SO code blocks on my pc. I'm sure
  the font has been there for several months.
- I have no idea what
  Windows apps will be affected by uninstalling it. (Probably VS Code
  and Windows Terminal).
- I apologize for posting about something so local and
  specific to my pc. It looked convincingly like an SO rollout.